# INSERT with two SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I am currently trying but I am receiving an mySQL error:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO profile_tag (profile_id, tag_id) 
(SELECT profile_id FROM profile WHERE username = '$username'), 
(SELECT tag_id FROM  tag WHERE  tag = '$music' OR tag = '$sports' OR tag = '$tech')");
```

I am able to complete an `INSERT` using a single `SELECT` statement however, not two.

The error I receive:

> Query is invalid: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'(SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag = '' OR tag = 'sports' OR tag = '')'` at line 1

Comment: Showing us the error might be helpful :-)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: `mysql` is no longer recommended to be used. You should be using `mysqli_query(...)` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: thanks guys for the heads up, I will read the tutorial but any ideas the multiple select would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much like the error says, the syntax is incorrect.  The values of the insert has to match the number of values in the column definition.

```
INSERT INTO profile_tag (profile_id, tag_id)
SELECT
    profile_id, tag_id
FROM
    profile
    CROSS JOIN tag
WHERE
    username = ?
    AND tag IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Note that this will insert *multiple* rows if a `tag` value is found for each of the inputs, but I believe that is what you want.

Comment: This almost did the job! When run the query the first time, it works correctly, the second time my output in the table is not as I expected it to be. A profile 1 has tags 2 and 3 which shows correctly. Then when ran again for a profile 2 with tags 1 and 3 the output provides instead a profile 1,2,1,2 with tags 1,1,3,3?

Comment: @user1888378 it's hard for me to say unless you give me the specific queries and table contents

Comment: Sorry! It did work, my testing resulted in me keeping the usernames the same by accident and therefore messing with the numbers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VALUES` clause

```
insert into profile_tag(user_id, tag_id) values
((select id from users where username = 'alice'),
 (select id from tags where tag = 'music'));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76439/1/0

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO profile_tag (profile_id, tag_id) 
(SELECT profile.profile_id, tag.tag_id FROM profile LEFT JOIN tag ON 1 WHERE profile.username = '$username' AND tag.tag IN ('$music', '$sports', '$tech'))");
```